# Python：Fail to reverse a list in global frame with an assignment statement in a function

Tags: python

For example, if I write the following code:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3]
```

Then I can reverse lst using the following code:

```
>>> lst = lst[::-1]
>>> lst
[3, 2, 1]
```

However, when I tried this:

```
>>> def rev(lst):
...     lst = lst[::-1]
...
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> rev(lst)
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3]
```

The above output shows lst is not reversed successfully.
How to explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your list is passed "by reference" so to speak. But then with the assignment you create a *new* object, and since you're not returning it, it's lost. Just check the `id`s of the objects to see that:

```
def rev(lst):
    print(id(lst))
    lst=lst[::-1]
    print(id(lst))

lst=[1,2,3]
rev1(lst)
                   
2503633156360
2503632976776
```

Comment: I agree. What a strange "feature" !

Answer (score 0):

```py
list1 = [1, 2, 3]

def rev(list2): # create function rev
  list = list2[::-1] # reverse the local list
  return list # you need this to return the value back, or it will go nowhere

list1 = rev(list1) # rev function will now return a value, so you save it to the list1 variable
print(list1) # [3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: But I think lst should have been changed even without "return", see the example:[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PyU1TSGtNC9ZI6e4RNOKixNIRRvEKtgqWFhYcHEBeUBmtKGOgpGOgnEsF1wlV0FRZl4JmKmgoPD/PwA "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")